# Gradle Zip complete parent project

Tags: gradle, zip

```
task fullZip(type: Zip) {
    baseName = 'fullZip'

    from projectDir.parentFile
    exclude 'build'
}
```

Looking to zip complete project, with the entire subprojects/modules.

Gradle task never completes and the size of the zip is building up to enormous size while it's a small project in general. 
This zip task is part of gradle file in one of the module.

From the half cooked zip file, I can see build directories, which should have been excluded are present.

Comment: Could you please show dir structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `exclude **/build/*`.

Comment: `from projectDir` only has the subproject/module files, I'm looking to zip the complete parent directory ignoring all the build folders.